# Why does my wrapper tag not work?

Tags: html, css, position, height, wrapper

I'm trying to create this site using a wrapper tag but it's not working and I have no idea why. Dreamweaver is saying somehow it's invalid but I have no idea how. Like if you look at this site: http://web.toolwire.com/croganm-1003/UserInterfaceDesign/Templates/WWVS.dwt

You can see that when you adjust the window size, the columns don't adjust height. That's fine, because I have a min-height on the wrapper. However, If I have text in the maincontent box, it just runs off the page. I want to avoid the use of `overflow-y:auto` and make it so the right column is always the same height but stays in the middle of the navbar and footer even though the footer will expand downward if text overflows maincontent and causes the box to expand (Which is what I'm trying to do) Here's my code:

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="doctitle" -->
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
    <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="head" -->
    <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
    <link href="../Module 10/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>


  <body>
    <div id="header" style="background-image:url(../Module%2010/website_design_dpk.png); height:300px; background-size:100% 100%;">

    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="Nav Bar" -->
        <li><a href="../Module 10/Index.html">Home Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Module 10/Intro.html">Introduction</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Module 10/Lesson.html">Lesson</a></li>
        <li><a href="../Module 10/Final.html">Final</a></li>
        <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="Main Content" -->
    <div id="wrapper">

      <div id="maincontent">

      </div>

      <!-- TemplateEndEditable --><!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="Background image" -->

      <div id="image" style="background-image: ;">

      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
    <div id="footer">
      Thank you for visitng WWVS! Please remember to check your pace schedule and remember if work is not submitted every 2 weeks, you will be removed from your course!
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### and here's my CSS:

```
/* CSS Document */
#header { /*Creates a div with a background image (created banner) and has the same 
            height and width as the image. The margins create a center aligned affect
            while making sure there is a 10px gap between the top of the page and 
            the header as well as a 10px gap below the header*/
    background-image: url(WWVS-Index-Header.png);
    height: 320px;
    width: 850px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
nav { /*Defines the navigation links. Left/Right auto margins make it center aligned,
        text align makes all nav links centered in their box and min width  makes it so 
        that when the page shrinks, the nav bar won't change shape and the nav div covers
        the entirity of the nav bar*/
    margin: 20px auto 50px auto;
    min-width:500px; 
    text-align: center;
    width:600px;;
}
#index {
    margin:20px auto 150px auto;
}
#index:hover
{
    margin: 20px auto 150px auto;
}
nav ul ul { /*Used to hide submenus*/
    display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul { /*Used to show submenus when you hover over a nav link*/
    display: block;
}
nav ul { /*Creates the nav bar layout and design. Default background in case CSS3 is not
        accepted. Gradient background if it is. Also have a box shadow for depth, padding
        to help the list have an equal amount of room in the box, and list-style and inline
        table and position help layout the table in a compact, clean fashion, and helps the
        nav bar realize we want this to display as a table*/
    background: #F6F6F6; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6 0%, #A0A0A0 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6 0%, #A0A0A0 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F6F6F6 0%,#A0A0A0 100%); 
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 9px 3px #666;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;  
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
nav ul li {/*Horizontal table, not vertical*/
    float: left;
    clear:right;
    position:relative;
}
nav ul li:hover {/* Changes color when you hover over list*/
    background: #78818C;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #78818C 60%, #5f6975 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #78818C 60%, #5f6975 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #78818C 60%,#5f6975 100%);
}
nav ul li:hover a {/*Changes text color to white to match the dark background when you
                    hover over the list*/
    color: #fff;
}       
nav ul li a {/*Formats text. The first 2 help with spacing and layout. The last two 
            affect color and the removes the underline from the link*/
    display: block; 
    padding: 25px 40px;
    color: #000; 
    text-decoration: none;
}   
nav ul ul { /*Formats sublists. Affects color as well as box shape (square). no padding
            to make boxes same size as other boxes. Top and position are used to keep
            the submenu right below the main menu*/ 
    background: #5f6975; 
    border-radius: 0px; 
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 100%;
    width:100%;
}
nav ul ul li {/*Affects the actual list of words of the submenus. Keeps boxes formated and
                and adds a border to submenu boxes to help readers designate those as
                a subpage*/
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a; 
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {/*Affects sublist links. Makes text white and give words some padding */
    padding: 15px 40px;
    color: #fff;
}   
nav ul ul li a:hover {/*Changes backgrond color of sublist when you hover over it */
    background: #4b545f;
}   
#wrapper {
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    min-height:450px;
    min-width:500px;
}
#maincontent { /*Affects the main content div. Gradient background color, box shadow,
                affects size of border radius to create rounded corners, padding (fluid),
                top margin to give the box room and right and bottom margin to give the box
                room. Font is sans-serrif, overflow is to keep the box at a set height and 
                float left is to help the box stay to the left side of the page. Font
                attributes to change font apperance. Width is 44% (Fluid).*/
    background: #FFF; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #FFF 0%, #DDD 60%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFF 0%, #DDD 60%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #FFF 0%,#DDD 60%); 
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 15px 2px #666;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 1% 1% 0px 1%;
    margin-right: 8%;
    margin-left: 3%;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 42%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
#image { /*Affects image. Nearly same as main content, however there is no granite background        and the float:left, clear:right makes the image appear in the same row as the
         main content. */
    width:42%;
    height:450px;
    position:absolute;
    float:left;
    clear:right;
    margin:auto;
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 15px 2px #666;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-left:0%;
    padding: 1% 1% 0px 1%;
    background-size: 100% 100% !important;
    right: 3%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#footer {/*Affects footer. Gradient bakcground, bold font, black text, center-aligned text,
            and aligned towards the bottom. Padding gives text room while the position,
            float and clear get box below images and maincontent */
    background: #FFF; 
    background: linear-gradient(top, #EEE 0%, #CCC 100%);  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #EEE 0%, #CCC 100%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #EEE 0%,#CCC 100%); 
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    min-height:70px;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
#footer a{ /*makes mailto: link and phone number underlined*/
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

### Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why can't you indent your code?

Comment: I'm sorry Praveen, what do you mean by indent my code?

Comment: Now that's indented code. Are you a developer?

Comment: Not so much. Web Design Student.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add overflow:auto to #maincontent id in css. Also do the same for the #footer id in css.

Comment: Like I said before, wanted to avoid overflow. Don't want a scroll bar. Just want the right-sided column to stay in the middle of the navbar and footer while the left sided column expanded

Comment: remove height:100% from the #maincontent and add min-height
before footer div and a div and apply clear:both css command to that div
<div style="clear:both;"></div>